# How to disable multiple selections in checkboxGroupInput in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I have a `checkboxGroupInput` in my shiny app. It seems that the multiple selection is always enabled. What I need is to disable the multiple selection and only allow one selection at a time.

Does anyone know how to do that?  Shiny app example below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
        checkboxGroupInput("icons", "Choose icons:",
                           choiceNames =
                               list(icon("calendar"), icon("bed"),
                                    icon("cog"), icon("bug")),
                           choiceValues =
                               list("calendar", "bed", "cog", "bug")
        ),
        textOutput("txt")
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
        output$txt <- renderText({
            icons <- paste(input$icons, collapse = ", ")
            paste("You chose", icons)
        })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the `checkboxGroupInput` function. I'm surprised there is no argument like `multiple`.  Should I use other widget to serve that purpose? What should I use?

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId, label, choices = NULL, selected = NULL,
  inline = FALSE, width = NULL, choiceNames = NULL,
  choiceValues = NULL)
```

Comment: I'm not a shiny expert, but I think generally you would use radio buttons when you can only choose one option: shiny has `radioButtons`.

Comment: All you need to do is replace `checkboxGroupInput` with `radioButtons`.